# Delphi - what am I missing in this query

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4

I am trying to run this query but fail :

```
procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ClientDataSet1 do
begin
ClientDataSet1.Close;
ClientDataSet1.CommandText :='';
ClientDataSet1.CommandText :='select lokacije.[LOKACIJA_ID],lokacije.[RESORT_ID],'
+ 'lokacije.[HOTEL_ID],lokacije.[NAZIV],'
+ 'uporabniki.[RESORT_ID],uporabniki.[HOTEL_ID],uporabniki.[LOKACIJA_ID],'
+ 'uporabniki.[UPORABNIK],uporabniki.[GESLO],uporabniki.[PRAVICE] from LOKACIJE'
+ 'inner join UPORABNIKI on lokacije.[LOKACIJA_ID]=uporabniki.[LOKACIJA_ID]'
+ 'where lokacije.[NAZIV] = ''' + Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text + ''' '
+ 'ORDER BY Uporabniki.[UPORABNIK]';
ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
end;
```

I get the error :  "Remote error: No such table :LOKACIJEinner"

What am I missing here ???
Database is SQLite. The form that I am opening here is a modal one.The whole app is a datasnap one.This is Client side. Problem is actually this : I have many locations and I only need the data from the name of the location displayed by AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text.

Comment: `where lokacije.[NAZIV] = ' + Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text + ' '`

Comment: You're using the `.Text` property of a status bar panel...from another form... in an SQL query?  I think even a global variable would be slightly less sinful.

Comment: now I am getting  "Remote error near [Hotel]: syntax error" ...?

Comment: @J text should work just fine....

Comment: @user3181689 what is in your panel text? add watch to `CommandText` and copy value before `Open()` method

Comment: @teran - my panel text is displaying the name of the location.

Comment: @user3181689 OK, then add quotes to name of locataion.

 `where lokacije.[NAZIV] = ''' + Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text + ''' '`

Comment: @user3181689 - yes, it will *work*.  It's just extremely bad practice.

Comment: cant make this work ... now I am getting "Remote error: No such table LOKACIJEinner" ?? Its not a typo  by the way on my part....

Comment: LOL, check that query twice before you execute it. Now you're missing space. It is so obvious. The error tells you "*No such table* ***LOKACIJEinner***" so first you can think of is a concatenated string of ***LOKACIJE*** and ***inner*** because of missing space...

Comment: The same applies one line below. There you're also missing a space at the closing quote char.

Comment: @J... : But at least with the OP's version, it's obvious from reading the CommandText assignment exactly where the value plugged into the SQL comes from.  Using a variable/property/function to represent the value just introduces an unhelpful level of indirection, ime (as I've found me quietly cursing myself for having done it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is more readable

```
procedure OpenLokacije(ANaziv: String);
begin
   ClientDataSet1.Close;
   ClientDataSet1.CommandText :=  ' select lokacije.[LOKACIJA_ID],'+    // AS Lok_LOKACIJA_ID
                                  '        lokacije.[RESORT_ID],'+
                                  '        lokacije.[HOTEL_ID],'+
                                  '        lokacije.[NAZIV],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[RESORT_ID],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[HOTEL_ID],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[LOKACIJA_ID],'+ // AS Upor_LOKACIJA_ID
                                  '        uporabniki.[UPORABNIK],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[GESLO],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[PRAVICE]'+
                                  ' from LOKACIJE'+
                                  '         inner join UPORABNIKI on lokacije.lokacija_id=uporabniki.lokacija_id '+
                                  ' where lokacije.[NAZIV] = :@NAZIV'+
                                  ' order by Uporabniki.[UPORABNIK]';
 ClientDataSet1.Parameters.ParamByName('@NAZIV').Value:= ANaziv;
 ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
```

`lokacije.lokacija_id` and `uporabniki.lokacija_id` are the same value and field respectively.

use AS:

```
lokacije.lokacija_id as lok_lokacija_id
uporabniki.lokacija_id  as  upo_lokacija_id
```

Also use the schema of the database like

```
dbo.uporabniki.lokacija_id
```

Comment: Wouldn't that `@` char fail execution ? I've never seen it used for parameters...

Comment: Just changed : "ClientDataSet1.Params.ParamByName('@NAZIV').Value:= '' + Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text + '' ;"

Comment: @user3181689, the "magic" of parameters is that you don't need to care about enclosing chars. You're just passing values to the `Value` property. The rest is upon provider. Anyway, with this code you should only pass that `Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text` into the `ANaziv` input parameter when calling this `OpenLokacije` procedure.

Comment: @Ravaut 123 - why am I getting two extra fields :resort_ID_1 and LOKACIJA_ID_1 in query result ????

Comment: @user3181689: two same result in the sql script. lokacije.[LOKACIJA_ID] and uporabniki.[LOKACIJA_ID]

Comment: @user3181689, you're having ambiguous names in your resultset. Look how to use `AS` expressions for [`result columns`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#result-column). Besides, you don't even need to fetch `LOKACIJA_ID` columns from both tables since they are joining your tables, so their values will be same. Similar you will probably see also for `HOTEL_ID` columns. Ravaut, sorry for this chaos :-)

Comment: Ahh,I got it... well,just removed them from the grid view and ok....@TLama,you know, I was just thinking the same....:)

Comment: @TLama: No sorry. It's ok. ;-)

Comment: sorry to bother you but ...what must I do to have (on new record of the mentioned query) the values of RESORT_ID and [HOTEL_ID] already entered in the grid?

Comment: personally, I don't insert data on a grid with 'joins'. also no deleting form the grid.

Comment: cancel the insert of ClientDataSet1 and use insert sqlscript, then requery the ClientDataSet1